# how to pass an index of picture to slider

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a picture slider, where src picture are getting dynamically from an array. I dont know exactly how to pass an index of array's picture. Now when I press next arrow my first picture change for the last one. How to pass one active picture to HTML template?

HTML

```
<div class="sliderItau">
<a class="prevButton"> <img alt="prevButton" src="/images/prev.png"></a>
<div class="jcarousel">
  <img id="image" src="/img1.jpg" alt=""></div>
<a class="nextButton"><img alt="nextButton" src="/images/next.png"></a>
</div>
```

JS

```
let slideIndex = 1
const imagesItau = [
    'img1.jpg',
    'img2.jpg',
    'img3.jpg',
    'img4.jpg'
]

 const showSlidesItau = function () {
    imagesItau.map((e, index) => {
        console.log(img.src)
        console.log(index)
        return document.getElementById('image').src = e
    })
}

const plusSlidesItau = function (n) {
    showSlidesItau((slideIndex += n))
}

next.addEventListener('click', function () {
    plusSlidesItau(+1)
})
```

Comment: show console error here if any

Comment: tere is not errors. console.log(img.src) shows me all src links in html tags. console.log(index) show all indexs

Comment: `src picture are getting dynamically from an array`. Code for this? You have given hardcoded `src` to `img`

Comment: `console.log(index) show all indexs` because you have loop i.e. map which will iterate through all items of your array

Comment: yes I know. I did this to check what I have in index and img.src. The problem I supose is in a function showSlidesItau. here I should pass somethig, some index of picture. But really I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, i think it's like that how you supposed it to work:
https://jsfiddle.net/fqLz27m3/

```
let slideIndex = 0
const imagesItau = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=1',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=2',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=3',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=4'
]

const showSlidesItau = function (n) {
document.getElementById('image').src = imagesItau[n];
console.log(imagesItau[n]);
console.log(n);
}

const plusSlidesItau = function (n) {
    showSlidesItau((slideIndex += n))
};


const nextButton = document.querySelector(".nextButton");

nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    plusSlidesItau(1)
})
```

1. Changed initial index from 1 to 0 for more easy access to the image via array.
2. Removed map function from *showSlidesItau* function, you can access images without map.
3. Click on next didn't work because you addded EventListener to nonexistent element.

Comment: Thank you Qwe. This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

This code works.

```
<div class="sliderItau">
    <button class="prevButton" onclick="BackOne()"></button>
    <div class="jcarousel">
        <img id="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Un1.svg/900px-Un1.svg.png" alt="" width="100" height="100"></div>
    <button class="nextButton" onclick="ForwardOne()"></button>
</div>
```

```
let slideIndex = 1
const imgs = [
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Un1.svg/900px-Un1.svg.png',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Deux.svg/800px-Deux.svg.png',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Trois.svg/800px-Trois.svg.png',
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Quatre.svg/800px-Quatre.svg.png'
]

const BackOne = () => {
    if (imgs.indexOf(document.getElementById('image').src) === 0) {
        document.getElementById('image').src = imgs[imgs.length - 1]
    } else {
        document.getElementById('image').src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(document.getElementById('image').src) - 1]
    }
}

const ForwardOne = () => {
    if (imgs.indexOf(document.getElementById('image').src) === imgs.length - 1) {
        document.getElementById('image').src = imgs[0]
    } else {
        document.getElementById('image').src = imgs[imgs.indexOf(document.getElementById('image').src) + 1]
    }
}
```

This isn't very decorated but i'll leave that to you.

Comment: Ok I have changed this part of code. So now I have first pic, and after click I have the last one. I dont know which argument I have to add.. thought should be some index, but not. i think there is an issue of this script. What I have to pass in this function.

Comment: I made this such that if it reaches image 4 and u still press forward, it will cycle back to image 1.

Answer (score 1):

this one is cycling backwards and forwards, if that's the functionality you want. tried to make the function names as clear as possible, so they describe exactly what they do. i hope you understand this code better:

```
<div class="sliderItau">
    <button id="prevButton">
        <img alt="prevButton" src="/images/prev.png" />
    </button>
    <div class="jcarousel">
        <img
            id="image"
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Un1.svg/900px-Un1.svg.png"
            alt=""
            width="100"
            height="100"
        />
    </div>

    <button id="nextButton">
        <img alt="nextButton" src="/images/next.png" />
    </button>
</div>

<script>
    const imagesItau = [
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Un1.svg/900px-Un1.svg.png',
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Deux.svg/800px-Deux.svg.png',
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Trois.svg/800px-Trois.svg.png',
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Quatre.svg/800px-Quatre.svg.png',
    ];
    let slideIndex = 0;

    const nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
    const prevButton = document.getElementById('prevButton');
    const img = document.getElementById('image');

    const applyNextImage = () => {
        const nextIndex = (slideIndex + 1) % imagesItau.length;
        applyImage(nextIndex);
        slideIndex = nextIndex;
    };

    const applyPreviousImage = () => {
        const nextIndex =
            slideIndex === 0
                ? imagesItau.length - 1
                : (slideIndex - 1) % imagesItau.length;
        applyImage(nextIndex);
        slideIndex = nextIndex;
    };

    const applyImage = index => {
        console.log(imagesItau[index]);
        img.src = imagesItau[index];
    };

    nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        applyNextImage();
    });
    prevButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        applyPreviousImage();
    });
</script>
```